# Communicating between a native app and MS Edge or IE in Enhanced Protected Mode?

Tags: internet-explorer, chromium, microsoft-edge

Is there any plan to allow Edge and EPM IE to **communicate over loopback**, or some other way for a **webapp to communicate with a native app**?

I'm working on a product where we would like a webapp to be able to communicate with a native app running on the same machine. We currently have a mechanism where the native app runs a **webserver listening on loopback** and the webapp makes CORS requests to this webserver. This mechanism works in most browsers except for EPM IE and Edge, where **loopback communication is disabled** (see "Loopback-blocked" in this [MSDN post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/03/23/understanding-ie10-enhanced-protected-mode-network-security-addons-cookies-metro-desktop.aspx)).

The answer to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896958/xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x80070005-access-is-denied-on-microsoft-edge-bu) suggested that there might be changes to this, but it sounded like that would only be for *development/debugging*, not for *production*. It would be great if someone could confirm that.

Related to this, **Chromium** announced similar plans to block loopback/local network access in the bug [Block sub-resource loads from the web to private networks and localhost](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=378566). However, there seemed to be quite an outcry and it sounded like they wouldn't implement a change without having a **replacement mechanism** in place.

Ideally we'd prefer a solution that didn't require proxying through our server because of the extra latency and complexity that would introduce.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [link](http://dev.modern.ie/platform/faq/how-can-i-debug-localhost/) in that same SO question, a future update will include the ability to enable localhost loopback support in `about:flags`.

Comment: Yes, I could ask my users to do that, and I could also run the `CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n=Microsoft.Windows.Spartan_cw5n1h2txyewy` command in my native app's installer, but it seems strange for me to change the security profile of all of Edge in order for my app to work.

Comment: The reason it's a global thing is that this localhost loopback is a way for a browser to communicate with a native-code application very freely. If a bad native program were installed, then it could do harm on its own, but it's still an unnecessary attack vector to leave open. I would guess it's been involved in a number of exploits over the years that have been patchable, but generally suggest it's a risky area.

Answer (score 0):

The FAQ at http://dev.modern.ie/platform/faq/how-can-i-debug-localhost/ changed recently:

> Microsoft Edge allows localhost access by default starting with Windows 10 build 10166+. This can be disabled via "about:flags".

So that fixes it at least for the Edge browser.