# Edge browser http request not working

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge

Invoking third party url by http request is not working in Edge browser.
Am using this code

```
$http({
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization':Authorization,
    },
    data: 'grant_type=client_credentials'
}).then(function (data, status, headers, config) {});
```

Comment: Is it working fine in other browsers ?

Comment: Yes its working in firefox and chrome...

Comment: What error do you see in console ? Press `F12` to open up `Developer Tools` and navigate to `Console`. See if something pops up in console.

Comment: am getting this error - XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.

Comment: I think its a problem with edge on localhost testing. Try this [Edge localhost testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896958/xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x80070005-access-is-denied-on-microsoft-edge-bu#30910398)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because of cross-domain of web browser policy which prohibit a request to not same host.

Comment: Am getting this error
XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.