# IE11 HTTPS AJAX XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2eff, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002eff

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, post, jboss

I have an ajax POST request that can take anywhere between 2 seconds to 30+ minutes. The post request occurs as a result of button click

If the request takes less than a minute or two, it comes back with a response and everything works fine. However if the request takes longer than two minutes it comes back with "Network error: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2eff, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002eff".

Ofcourse, it works fine Firefox and Chrome.

The application is deployed on a JBoss server with SSL enabled. The architecture here is that we have a load balancer that routes the request to two Jboss servers.

Internet Explorer

Version: 11.0.9600.180971C
Update: 11.0.25

**I have tried the following but in vain**

1) ajax set cache to false - did not work
2) Changed registry settings as per https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/813827 - did not work, here is where it gets confusing, thissuggests it is not an IE thing, but at the same time this works on chrome and ff so its not a server thing too
3) Set ajax timeout to 0 - did not work
4) Added e.preventDefault after  $('#mdlSgn').click(function() { as per [jQuery Ajax requests are getting cancelled without being sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577275/jquery-ajax-requests-are-getting-cancelled-without-being-sent)

```
$('#mdlSgn').click(function() {
    $('#cnfdsgl').modal('hide');

     $.ajax({
        url: ajaxUrl,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(input),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
             /// some logic


        },
        error : function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            /// some logic
        }
    });

 //some other logic
});
```

Comment: Yea I know it takes 30 minutes and the users are fine with it, they want to see a success response after that

Comment: You've got some understanding users. If it were me, I'd have the server respond immediately, put the task in a work queue, and then notify when the thing is done and the results are available.

Comment: Well thats one way to do it, but the thing is that it was working fine before and I wanted to know the root cause of why IE behaves like that?

Comment: Why not do the processing not as part of the original request (which to call processing asynchronously and return immediately), but instead to have some kind of status/state request, that you can call on regular intervals to check if the processing has finished?

Answer (score 21):

We spend multiple days searching for the cause of this problem!

- In the console: *SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2eff, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002eff.*
- In the network tab of IE/Edge, we see the failed request as 'Pending...'
- XmlHTTPRequest/JQuery returns 404 error at the client, but the server returned a successfully 200 response.
- No response headers returned

We only had this problem when using all of these:

- HTTP/2
- POST requests
- Windows 10
- IE or Edge

Apparently it is a **Windows 10 bug** in the HTTP stack that is now solved in Windows 10 version 1803 (April 2018).
So normally this problem will disappear over time for people/companies using auto updates of Windows. [used Windows 10 versions WorldWide](https://reports.adduplex.com)

We tested this on an older and newer version of Windows 10 and it is indeed solved.

Some temporary solution could be:

- disable HTTP/2 for IE and Edge and use HTTPS (server side change).
- use GET (if possible)
- does PUT also has this problem?
- do some retries if no response headers are returned
- accept that IE/Edge users will be punished ;-)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this!

Comment: And here I am with an app that *has* to be supported in IE.

Comment: Actually I have a question about this - I'm currently on windows *7*, not 10, version 6.1.7601 - is this issue also present in Win 7?

Answer (score 7):

> > can take anywhere between 2 seconds to 30+ minutes

I assume this is because of large amount of data to transfer.

I have creating large file uploader, that handles 20GB+ video files and may last for several hours.

In my experience - uploading large data with single ajax request can cause strange browser crashes (for example my Chrome browser crashes in about 20% of upload tests).

The most reliable way, what I found, is to split data in chunks of 1MB and send them sequentially to the server by separate ajax requests.

Comment: I can describe detailed example, if you need it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Amber, however this is not for file uploads, it is the backend process that takes that much time...

Comment: @user1707141 I found workaround for error code which you mentioned,  try it: "Open up Internet Options, choose the Advanced tab, and then click the "Restore Advanced Settings" button. After that the Ajax requests worked fine."

Comment: The IE settings in our company are determined by the System Admin and hence I do not have much flexibility in that..

Comment: can you provide me with the code for the large file upload? im facing the same issue for a control i did for drag and drop uploading using jquery.filedrop.js and mvc

Comment: @ChathuraSam, sure, but I need some time to prepare it. I think I will publish it on saturday.

Comment: @Ujeenator Thanks a lot. that will not be a problem :) Please provide me with the link when you do. :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was custom response code (3020) returned from server. Switched it to 200 and modified SPA client logics, this solved the issue.

Comment: Same with me. I returned 302 and old IE did not like it. Switching to 200 did solve the problem.