# Ajax Request Aborted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am doing an ajax call. It works fine in local. After deploying the application into environment, the ajax call is aborted.In Ie I can see the following Error:

XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2eff, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002eff.

Please refer below for the ajax request code:

```
var refreshThisDiv = "idDiv";
var postUrl = "/UserData/getAllUserNames?id=" + id;
var httpRequest = null;
var refreshContent = "null";
httpRequest = XMLHTTPObject();
httpRequest.open("POST", postUrl, true);
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
  doAjax(refreshThisDiv, httpRequest);
};
httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
httpRequest.send(null);

function doAjax(refreshThisDiv, httpRequest) {

    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
      if (httpRequest.status == 200) `enter code here` {
          var response = httpRequest.responseText;
          if (response != 'null') { 
              //do Something
          }
          else {
             //ajax failed
          }
```

Its always going to //ajax failed. I am not sure what is the issue as I cant see any error in Console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527387/script7002-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2ef3-could-not-complete-the-operati)

Comment: @souldeux Hi. The error code is different in my case. So not sure if its the same case or not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049814/ie11-https-ajax-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2eff-could-not-complete-the-ope . Another one - https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T359974