# IE11 XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2eff, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002eff

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, internet-explorer-11

I have an ajax POST request like below,

```
$.ajax({
url: url,
type:"POST",
contentType:"application/html; charset=utf-8",
dataType:"html",
success: function(data) {
....
....
},
error: function() {
.....
}
});
```

It works perfectly fine when I try in chrome/firefox browsers any number of times.

In IE11,there are no issues when I use this function once or twice but when I invoke it multiple times continuosly (something like 10 to 12 times) I get the error as below in IE console.

> SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2eff, Could not complete
>   the operation due to error 00002eff.

I do not have this error for any of the local normal users but my application is getting stuck during performance tests when there are more number of hits sequentially.

The html content which I get in ajax call is very less. I have referred to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049814/ie11-https-ajax-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2eff-could-not-complete-the-ope?rq=1) in stack overflow but still unable to get the reason for this cause.

Application is deployed in Websphere Application Server 8.5. It's mandatory that the application should be compatible with IE11

Comment: @mplungjan The code which I get is 0x2eff but the other question says 0x2ef3 . Both are because of same problem ?

Comment: @mplungjan Yes ! I checked it before posting a question.

Comment: Who were you, DenverCoder9? What did you see?!