# IE 11 Issue: :SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2eff

Tags: asp.net-web-api, internet-explorer-11

I'm facing the below error in IE 11, I'm calling a webapi, though webapi response is coming fine but also getting the below error on console:

**SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2eff, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002eff.**

Please give any suggestion, what could be the root causes of this error, I'm not getting this error in other browsers (Chrome and Firefox)

Answer (score 0):

You've said that the error occurs when you call a webapi.

As far as I'm concerned, maybe this due to a large amount of data to transfer.

When you handle large data with single ajax request, it may make the browser crashing.

For more about the error,you may refer to the similar thread.

[IE11 HTTPS AJAX XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2eff, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002eff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049814/ie11-https-ajax-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2eff-could-not-complete-the-ope)

Comment: Thanks for replying, Actually I'm not fetching much data.