# IE XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied

Tags: javascript, java, angular, internet-explorer, devops

I'm trying to test my application. In Chrome it's working fine but in IE I'm getting this kind of error.

> SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.

Comment: based on a quick google it appears to be a CORS issue. add the cors header to the served file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE https CORS XHR request fails with Script7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2eff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25922043/ie-https-cors-xhr-request-fails-with-script7002-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0)

Comment: @Ramana I am facing same issue. Any solution did you get?

Comment: @sandy still I got this issue

Comment: @occam'sRazor thaks for your response, I already had CORS added to my headers, the same piece of code is working in chrome and Firefox bot not working in IE 11.

Comment: @Ramana did you get the solution ??

Comment: @Awesome No, I still had the issue in IE.